# Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

I am initializing the variables for SQLite database in the `WidgetData` class but there is an error I have got right now,

> Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

but previously it was running successfully.

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29673488/return-from-initializer-without-initializing-all-stored-properties) but even I have added them empty value still getting the error, help to resolve this.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
import Foundation

class WidgetData {

  var id: Int64?
  var name: String
  var entered : String
  var address: String

  var formid : Int64?
  var formname : String
  var formdescription : String
  var formcategory : String

  init(id: Int64) {
      self.id = id
      name = ""
      entered = ""
      address = ""
  }

  init(formid: Int64) {
      self.formid = formid
      formname = ""
      formdescription = ""
      formcategory = ""
  }

  init(id: Int64, name: String, entered: String, address: String) {
      self.id = id
      self.name = name
      self.entered = entered
      self.address = address
  }

  init(formid: Int64, formname : String, formdescription : String, formcategory : String) {
      self.formid = formid
      self.formname = formname
      self.formdescription = formdescription
      self.formcategory = formcategory
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the following properties:

```
var name: String
var entered : String
var address: String
var formname : String
var formdescription : String
var formcategory : String
```

are not optional, so they must be [initialized](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID212):

> Classes and structures must set all of their stored properties to an appropriate initial value by the time an instance of that class or structure is created. Stored properties cannot be left in an indeterminate state.
>
> You can set an initial value for a stored property within an initializer, or by assigning a default property value as part of the property’s definition.

Hence you could assign them a default value, so your code might be:

```
import Foundation

class WidgetData {
    var id: Int64?
    var name: String = ""
    var entered : String = ""
    var address: String = ""

    var formid : Int64?
    var formname : String = ""
    var formdescription : String = ""
    var formcategory : String = ""
    
    init(id: Int64) {
        self.id = id
    }
    
    init(formid: Int64) {
        self.formid = formid
    }
    
    init(id: Int64, name: String, entered: String, address: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.entered = entered
        self.address = address
    }
    
    init(formid: Int64, formname : String, formdescription : String, formcategory : String) {
        self.formid = formid
        self.formname = formname
        self.formdescription = formdescription
        self.formcategory = formcategory
    }
}
```