# How change .navigationBarTitle font in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode11

I'm using SwiftUI with Xcode 11 and I want to change `NavigationBarTitle` font with these lines of codes:

```
.navigationBarTitle (Text("Navigation Bar Title"), displayMode: .inline)
    .font(.subheadline)
```

but nothing happened. any suggestion or comment?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505528/swiftui-update-navigation-bar-title-color similar but not answered yet

Comment: One of the way is you can use Appearance API. or wait for  new version of swiftui

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In SwiftUI, at this point we can not change the `navigationBarTitle` font directly, but you can change navigationBar appearance like this,

```
struct YourView: View {
    init() {
        //Use this if NavigationBarTitle is with Large Font
        //UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [.font : UIFont(name: "Georgia-Bold", size: 20)!]

        //Use this if NavigationBarTitle is with displayMode = .inline
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [.font : UIFont(name: "Georgia-Bold", size: 20)!]
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello World!")
            //.navigationBarTitle("TEST")
            .navigationBarTitle (Text("TEST"), displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you. Thanks!!

Comment: This is not working for iOS 16> in my case.

Comment: Yea, iOS 16 gives - "Only unstyled text can be used with navigationTitle".

Answer (score 3):

You can't change `navigationBarTitle`'s font with `.font` modifier **yet** (Tested in Xcode 11-Beta2).

But you can build your own custom `navigationBarView` with complete access to any of its subviews like this:

```swift
struct NavigationBarView: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Style.Color.navigationBarColor)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                .frame(height: 0)

            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Style.Color.navigationBarColor)
                .frame(height: 64)
            .overlay(
                HStack() {
                    Image("close")
                    Spacer()

                    Text("سفر به سلامت")
                        .font(Style.Font.navigationTitle)
                        .color(Style.Color.darkTextColor)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)

                    Spacer()
                    Image("menu")
                }
            )

            Spacer()
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

Note that you will lose `LargeTitleStyle` with this implementation.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to create a NavigationBarBuilder.

```
struct NavigationBarBuilder: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    var build: (UINavigationController) -> Void = { _ in }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<NavigationBarBuilder>) -> UIViewController {

        UIViewController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<NavigationBarBuilder>) {

        if let navigationController = uiViewController.navigationController{
            self.build(navigationController)
        }
    }
}
```

and you can use it in your content view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("")
                .navigationBarTitle("Türkiye", displayMode: .inline)
                .background(NavigationBarBuilder {navigationController in
                    navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
                    navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
                })
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

Good luck...

Answer (score 2):

In SwiftUI 5 UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes doesn't work. You need to use one of the following to change the font in the title:

```
        init () {
            UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [.font : UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 20)!]
            // OR
            UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [.font:UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle:.text-style)]
        }
```

where .text-style could be found in UIFont.TextStyle documentation, e.g.

```
.caption
.body
.title1
.title2
.title3
etc
```

**Update 1** (to answer a qs about exact code in comments)

```
struct ContentView: View {

    init () {
        let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraph.alignment = .center
        
        UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [.font:UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle:.title2),
                                                                 .foregroundColor:UIColor.systemBlue,
                                                                 .paragraphStyle: paragraph
                                                                ]
```

...

then in body I have this. You should probably pay attention to displayMode param

```
// Body is in the same ContentView struct. Settings from init will be used in navigationBarTitle
// listView() is just a custom function returning a SwiftUI's List()

var body: some View {


        NavigationView {
            
        listView()
            .navigationBarTitle(
                Text(self.accts.selCount <= 0 ? "Accounts" : "\(self.accts.selCount) selected")
                ,
                displayMode:.large)
```

Comment: I'm not seeing this work. Tried in parent NavigationView's init and in child views. Can you share a brief example of exactly where this init is?

Comment: thanks, but I'm not sure I follow. The last block has a ViewBuilder body with three AnyViews and a TabView with an interior Navigation View. It's not clear where the init would be placed... in the view produced by func listView or something else. Can you write as a single buildable View struct? I do see the global override method working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67172529/14433738

Comment: @Ryan That's very standard. 'init' is a constructor of some "struct ContentView: View...". ContentView is used in SceneDelegate.scene function to setup initial view. 'var body' defines content's UI in the same ContentView struct. Not sure what is confusing. Both init and 'var body' are defined in the same ContentView class. In the body you need to pay attention to only one thing: navigationBarTitle

Comment: Updated the answer a bit to make clear that both 'init' and 'var body' are in the same ContentView struct, which is a root of all views.

Comment: The comment helps clarify the intent. Just FYI from a reader who has made some material apps with SwiftUI, the code formatting/syntax has all sorts of oddness with a split up ternary and parentheses and brackets perhaps mixed up or not copied in, which made some guesswork at what was happening. Maybe it's SO doing something with the paste-in. Thanks for the proposed solution route and taking the time to edit this, though.

Comment: Yes, formatting was not good. I've simplified the second part by removing unnecessary details. Hope readability is better now

Answer (score 0):

In my case the above answers did not work.
But the code below worked fine.

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        
appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.font : UIFont(name: "Georgia-Bold", size: 20)!]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Navigation title like below and enjoy. tested in [Xcode 14.3 - ios 16.4]

```
NavigationView { // <1>
    Text("Hello, SwiftUI!")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar { // <2>
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) { // <3>
                VStack {
                    Text("Title").font(.headline)
                    Text("Subtitle").font(.subheadline)
                }
            }
        }
}
.toolbarRole(.navigationStack)
```