# How do I change text attributes for a navigation bar title in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, uikit, swiftui

lately, I've been playing around with the new SwiftUI framework.

I do have a basic understanding of how the framework works but I cannot figure out a way to change title attributes for a navigation bar.

I am using the latest Xcode 11 beta 5 and the corresponding swift/swiftUI version

I already tried a few things.
First thing I tried was to just add modifiers to a Text, but somehow SwiftUI seems to ignore modifiers in a navigation bar environment.

The second thing I tried was to change the title attributes through `UINavigationBar.apperance().titleTextAttributes = ...`

but it seems like they removed the ability to customize titleTextAttributes of UINavigationBar in the latest beta version.

```
//First thing:
List(myData) {
  ...
}
.navigationBarTitle(Text("My title").font(myFont))


// Second thing
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = myAttrs
```

I expect the navigation bar title to have my custom font but it's always the apple default font.

Comment: Thank you! I tried it in the .onAppear() modifier.

Answer (score 4):

In SwiftUI, at this point we can not change `navigationBarTitle` font directly, but you can change navigationBar appearance like this,

```
struct YourView: View {
    init() {
        //Use this if NavigationBarTitle is with Large Font
        UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [.font : UIFont(name: "Georgia-Bold", size: 20)!]

        //Use this if NavigationBarTitle is with displayMode = .inline
        //UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [.font : UIFont(name: "Georgia-Bold", size: 20)!]
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello World!")
              .navigationBarTitle(Text("Dashboard").font(.subheadline), displayMode: .large)
            //.navigationBarTitle (Text("Dashboard"), displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you. Thanks!!

Comment: Yea, iOS 16 gives - "Only unstyled text can be used with navigationTitle". This should be fixed..

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work fine.

I store it in the @main struct (iOS 14) which i find cleaner than init() in the View.

```
extension UINavigationController {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor  .white]
        
        appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.font : UIFont(name: "OfficinaSans", size: 30)!]
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = [ .font : UIFont(name: "OfficinaSans", size: 20)!]
        appearance.shadowColor = .white
        
        navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
        navigationBar.compactAppearance = appearance
        navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
         
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Out of the dozens of duplicate questions and answers, this is only approach that works in iOS 14.5. View inits didn't work and ugh gross. That said, you may want to edit w/ standard and scrollEdge/Compact being separated in into different font sizes.

Comment: can do but -  my apps are only portrait so i didnt bother.  glad it helped.

Comment: let's trade lives?