# Navigation bar title does not remain bold upon font change

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, swiftui, uinavigationbar

I changed my navigation bar title to the Apple's New York serif typeface using this code (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56712641/how-change-navigationbartitle-font-in-swiftui)).

```
init() {
        // if NavigationBarTitle is with Large Font
        if let newYorkDescriptor = UIFontDescriptor.preferredFontDescriptor(withTextStyle: .largeTitle).withDesign(.serif) {
            UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [.font : UIFont(descriptor: newYorkDescriptor, size: 0)]
        }
    }
```

The navigation bar title shows up with the right font and font size, but it loses the bolded look that the normal navigation bar title has. How can I regain that? Is there a bold or font weight parameter I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bold` is part of font descriptor and you have to add it explicitly, like

```
UIFontDescriptor.preferredFontDescriptor(withTextStyle: .largeTitle)
     .withDesign(.serif)?.withSymbolicTraits(.traitBold)
```