# How can the background or the color in the navigation bar be changed?

Tags: navigationbar, swiftui

Currently I couldn't find any method to change the color/background of the navigation bar in SwiftUI. Any tips?

Answer (score 5):

In order to change color of navigation bar for all view controllers, you have to set it in `AppDelegate.swift` file

Add following code to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function in `AppDelegate.swift`

```
var navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()

navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = uicolorFromHex(0xffffff)
navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor = uicolorFromHex(0x034517)
```

In here `tintColor` attribute change the background color of the navigation bar.

`barTintColor` attribute affect to the color of the:

- back indicator image
- button titles
- button images

**Bonus:**

Change color of navigation bar title:

```
// change navigation item title color
navigationBarAppearace.titleTextAttributes =[NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

`titleTextAttributes` affect to the title text

I hope it helps. :)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough. The question is how to do it with the new SwiftUI API's directly. Thanks for the comment

Comment: So this doesn't seem to work as listed for current version of SwiftUI
What does work:
navigationBarAppearance.backgroundColor = ...

also:
navigationBarAppearance.tintColor = ...
changes the color of the icons, not barTintColor.

Answer (score 3):

In SwiftUI, at this point we can not change it directly, but you can change navigationBar appearance like this,

```
struct YourView: View {
    init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .orange

        //Use this if NavigationBarTitle is with Large Font
        UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [.font : UIFont(name: "Georgia-Bold", size: 20)!]

        //Use this if NavigationBarTitle is with displayMode = .inline
        //UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [.font : UIFont(name: "Georgia-Bold", size: 20)!]
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello World!")
              .navigationBarTitle(Text("Dashboard").font(.subheadline), displayMode: .large)
            //.navigationBarTitle (Text("Dashboard"), displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you. Thanks!!

Comment: Note that you are changing the appearance of the `UINavigationBar` globally and not only for this view. All new `NavigationView`s will have these colors as well.

Answer (score 2):

Till now there is no definitive API in SwiftUI for this purpose. But you can use the appearance API. Here is a sample code.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.red]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .green
    }
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            NavigationButton(destination: SecondPage(), label: {
                Text("Click")
            })
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Title"), displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use below line it will works
1) .navigationBarTitle(Text("Title")) 
2) .navigationBarTitle(Text("Title"), displayMode: .large)

Comment: I am not sure how does it change the background color of a navigation bar? Can you provide a code snippet that works.

Answer (score 1):

Put a `Rectangle` behind your `NavigationView` inside a `ZStack`:

```
ZStack {
    Rectangle().foregroundColor(.red)
    NavigationView {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58427754/467209) for a solution that does not use `.appearance()`.

In short use `UIViewControllerRepresentable`

```swift
func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<NavigationConfigurator>) {
    uiViewController.navigationController?.navigationBar...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With [Introspect](https://github.com/timbersoftware/SwiftUI-Introspect) you could do it this way:

```
NavigationView {
    Text("Item 2")
    .introspectNavigationController { navigationController in
        navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for this answer , if you use `UINavigationBar.appearance()` on `init()` or on `onAppear()` it will effect the whole app not only you current view, but you solution effect the view itself only, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note that I didn't at first understand: SwiftUI will change the appearance of things like NavigationBar based on whether you are in night mode.

If you want to default it to a different color scheme add

```
.colorScheme(.dark)
```

If you create a color scheme using the color set system as outlined in this post: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-design-system-with-swiftui/ it would apply to the main elements like navigations and tab bars, and allow you to apply different schemes for night/day mode.

Answer (score 0):

The `NavigationView` is managing full screens of content. Each of those screens has its own background color. Therefore you can use the following approach to apply your Background color onto the screens:

```swift
let  backgroundColor = Color(red: 0.8, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9)

extension View {
    func applyBackground() -> some View {
        ZStack{
            backgroundColor
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            self
        }
    }
}
```

Then you apply it to all your screens:

```swift
NavigationView {
    PrimaryView()
        .applyBackground()

    DetailView(title: selectedString)
        .applyBackground()
}
```

Be aware: some SwiftUI views have their own background color which is overriding yours (e.g. `Form` and `List` depending on context)

Answer (score -1):

## iOS 16

You can set any color to the background color of any toolbar background color (including the navigation bar) for the inline state with these two simple native modifiers (both needed):

###### Xcode 14

```
.toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
.toolbarBackground(.yellow, for: .navigationBar)
```

#### Notes:

1. The color will be set on the entire bar (up to the top edge of the screen).
2. `toolbarBackground` **MUST** be `visible` to see the color
3. both modifiers should be applied on the `content`, **NOT** the `NavigationStack` (or `NavigationView`) itself!

[image: Demo]