# How to align NavigationBarItems using large title like in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swiftui

In iOS 13 many apps have the **navigationBarItems** aligned horizontally with the navigationBarTitle.

**WHAT I WANT**

TO ACHIEVE
[image]

**RESULTS I GOT**

RESULT 1
[image]

RESULT 2
[image]

**How do you achieve the same result in SwiftUI?**

I have tried using some .top padding but when you scroll the "+" button does not move.

Thanks!

Comment: The short answer is you can't. The examples you've shown are Apple apps and they haven't exposed a way to do this for 3rd party developers in UIKit-land or SwiftUI. If these were available, the first clue would be they'd appear on `UINavigationItem` or `UINavigationBar` but they do not. My guess is this will get exposed sometime in the future.

Comment: @Procrastin8, not to disagree - I'm not - but this is clearly tagged `SwiftUI` along with mentioning it (in bold) in the question. Why bring up `UINavigationItem` or `UINavbigationBar`, which are both part of `UIKit`?

Comment: ext comment, to @Arthur. This really isn't a good question. Three links, no code, and very vague. (Is your **specific** issue that the "+" button doesn't move or something related to a `NavigationView`?) Seriously, don't link to your results - show us code, tell us what is wrong with the results, and tell us something we can actually duplicate. As is? Hard to say what the issue (or solution) is.

Comment: @dfd I think Procrastin8 mentioned UINavigationItem and other UIKit elements beucase at the moment, NavigationView is implemented using the old UIKit elements. In fact if you want to change some properties of the NavigationView, you have to customize the UINavigationBar.appereance. In the future apple should give use ways to customize NavigationView without using the UIKit elements.

Comment: @dfd There was no need to show any code because I could not find any way to implement what apple has achieved. Anyone who has used SwiftUI knows what padding is. Obviously the problem is not with the "+" button, but with ANY navigationBarItem you want to align horizontally with the title !!

Comment: does the answer from this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57338785/swiftui-custom-navigation-bar-with-list

Comment: @yawnobleix not really.. thank you anyway!