# SwiftUI Navigation Bar Colour

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to build a master/detail type sample application and I'm struggling to get the NavigationBar UI to work correctly in my detail view. The code for the view I am working on is as follows:

```
struct JobDetailView : View {

    var jobDetails: JobDetails

    var body: some View {

            Form {

                Section(header: Text("General")) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Job Name")
                        Spacer()
                        Text(jobDetails.jobName)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    }

                    HStack {
                        Text("Hourly Rate")
                        Spacer()
                        Text(TextFormatters().currencyString(amount: jobDetails.hourlyRateBasic!))
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    }
                }

            }   .padding(.top)
                .navigationBarTitle(Text(jobDetails.jobName))
    }
}
```

The reason for the `.padding(.top)` is to stop the Form overlapping the navigation bar when scrolling upwards.

The white background on the navigation bar portion my issue (first image), I should expect it to be in keeping with the overall style of the UI, what I expect to happen is shown in the second image.

I have tried to add foreground/background colours and Views to change this colour, but to no avail. I'm also reticent of forcing a colour for the NagivationBar, as this will require further configuration for use with dark mode.

[Current view when running application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfVoj.png)

[Expected view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5czhx.png)

Comment: Check out this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56581462/10200990

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no available (SwiftUI) API for doing that (yet) (beta 5).

But we could use `UINavigationBar.appearance()`, as in:

`UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear`

> Full Code

```
import SwiftUI

struct JobDetailView: View {

    init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("General")) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Job Name")
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Scientist")
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text("Hourly Rate")
                        Spacer()
                        Text("$ 1.00")
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    }
                }

            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Scientist")
            .navigationBarHidden(false)
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct JobDetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        JobDetailView()
    }
}
#endif
```

> Result

[image: result]

> Dark Mode Result

[image: result dark]

Comment: Thanks very much, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Did not work for me when I added a background to the View inside NavigationView.

Comment: This works but it changes it for the entire app. @iSpain17 make sure you put it in the first view that loads.

Comment: Is there any way to change the background in other part of swiftUi view instead of init()

Answer (score 2):

<sub>You don't need to change anything **for your issue** now (since it is the default behavior of SwiftUI). But about the title of your question:</sub>

#### From iOS 16

You can set any color to the background color of any toolbar background color (including the navigation bar) for the inline state with a simple native modifier:

```
.toolbarBackground(.yellow, in: .navigationBar)
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: Would you be willing to add a code sample on how to use this?