# NavigationBarTitle color change for watchOS in SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, navigationbar, watchos-6

[image]

In the image above id like to change `-02:49` to a color such as `Color.blue`

I've tried:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        PlayerView().accentColor(Color.blue)

    }
}
```

and 
I've also tried adding it in the actual PlayerView as follows:

```
struct PlayerView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            .... 

        }.navigationBarTitle(Text(“-2:49”))
         .accentColor(.blue)

    }

}
```

I've also tried:

```
   struct PlayerView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            .... 

        }.navigationBarTitle(Text(“-2:49”).foregroundColor(.blue))

    }

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At this point for change color of navigationBarTitle their is no direct api in SwiftUI.
But you can change it like this,
1) Go to `Interface.storyboard` file inside your `AppName WatchKit App`. 
2) Select `Hosting Controller Scene`, Go to `File Inspector` and change `Global Tint` to your Custom Color.

Answer (score 21):

With WatchOS7/Xcode12 using the SwiftUI App Lifecycle you won't have a storyboard.

There is now an AccentColor within the App assets which is how you can change it.

[image: Xcode12 Accent Color]

Answer (score 6):

Here is the code if anyone want to change color of navigation title in WatchOS

```
.navigationTitle {    
  Text("Header").foregroundColor(.blue) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The modifier to change text colour is .foregroundColor(), so you should write:

```
Text(“-2:49”).foregroundColor(.blue)
```

Accent colour is what was known in UIKit as tint colour, i.e. the colour of clickable items. ForegroundColor is used for nonclickable items to give them a certain colour.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the question. The last example I provided should have been `Text(“-2:49”).foregroundColor(.blue)` not  `Text(“-2:49”).font(.blue)` foregroundColor on the NavigationBarTitle doesn't seem to work.

Comment: There’s also a modifier called .colorMultiply(.blue) which doesn’t do exactly what you are after, but might just do the trick.

Comment: I tried it. The issue is that the NavigationBarTittle is expecting something of type StringProtocol and using `colorMultiply` changes the Text View into `some View` therefore I get the error:  `Argument type 'some View' does not conform to expected type 'StringProtocol'`

Comment: Yes, colorMultiply is modifier on views. It might mean that you cannot really modify much. A hack that might work is to invert the bar only to be rightToLeft and then have no title and insert your text as a button that does nothing. It would have the tint colour by default.

Comment: Using UIKit you set the tintColor parameter to get the desired behavior. There should be an equivalent using SwiftUI but I can't seem to find it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: In [this video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/219/) you can clearly see they were able to change the color

Comment: Yes right but we are not able to see from where they are changing navigationBarTitle color.

Answer (score 0):

@CodeChimp's answer is correct but not perfect. If you're updating from old project to SwiftUI, you also need to set up asset catalog compiler in your target like this;

[image]

If you don't have any Interface which means you completely adopt to SwiftUI. For this condition, you need to select **"WatchKit Extension"** target and make changes.