# How do I set the navigation title colour on WatchOS

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos

I can't figure out how to set the navigation title colour on my watch OS app. I've tried everything I can think of, but it's always grey.

How do I make "My App" blue in this example

```swift
    @main
    struct GiveBloodApp: App {
    
        @StateObject var appModel = AppModel()

        @SceneBuilder var body: some Scene {
            WindowGroup {
                NavigationView {
                Text("Hello World").multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .navigationTitle("My App")
                }
            }                      
        }
    }
```

Comment: This actually is not possible with SwiftUI as far as I know and can only be achieved with UIKit. See this older post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58035341/navigationbartitle-color-change-for-watchos-in-swiftui

Comment: I’m pretty sure it adopts the accent color if set

Comment: That was the problem. I had to change the accent color resource. Didn't even realize it was there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NavigationBarTitle color change for watchOS in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58035341/navigationbartitle-color-change-for-watchos-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 1):

Update your navigationTitle with the following to compose its contents and describe the colour.

```
.navigationTitle {
    Text("Your App").foregroundColor(.red)
}
```