# SwiftUI: Disable translucence in NavigationView

Tags: swiftui

I'm working on rewriting an app to SwiftUI. Currently I'm struggling with what seems an easy one: Disabling the translucence in NavigationView.

The code I used before is:

```swift
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

But isTranslucent is not in the autocomplete suggestions.

If I put it anyway, the app crashes inside the ViewRendererHost.render(interval:updateDisplayList:) :

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1c34016a0)
```

Did I miss something? How can I disable the translucence of NavigationView in SwiftUI?

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: Finally I noticed that using the default displayMode "large" or "automatic" (default), the NavigationBar is not translucent by default. It only has this but when using .navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .inline). Therefore for this project I will have to use the large displayMode.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug, and you will instead have to continue using `UINavigationController`. You can still have all your content as SwiftUI in `UIHostingController`s, but you will have to keep the UIKit navigation stack or it'll explode.

Comment: I hope this will be fixed in future release. Meanwhile the suggestion to continue using ```UINavigationController``` is valid. Thanks

Comment: @Gregor I have the same issue. Can you share working code? Still possible to override via App Delegate?

Comment: @George: No working code yet...I sent a feedback to Apple regarding this issue and I'm still waiting for an answer.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks for the reply! Hopefully they fix, blocking from finishing my app.

Comment: Found a better solution, without the need of .appearance(): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505528/swiftui-update-navigation-bar-title-color