# SwiftUI change navigationBarTitle color with button

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar

can I change navigationBarTitle color when touched a button?

```
NavigationView {
    ZStack {
        Color(ThemeManager.shared().generalBackgroundColor)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }    .navigationBarTitle("Change theme sample").foregroundColor(.blue)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot currently change navigation bar properties in SwiftUI natively, so your `.foregroundColor(.blue)` will just change *all* the foreground colors on that screen.

You can use something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58427754/467209) to gain access to the `UINavigationController` and then change the large title bar with `navigationController.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue]`.