# SwiftUI – How to set the title of a NavigationView to large title (or small)?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uinavigationcontroller, swiftui-navigationview

Using SwiftUI how do I change the navigation bar's title size? Choosing between a standard or a large title.

[image: Difference between a large and a standard (inline) title]

Answer (score 61):

## SwiftUI (iOS 14+)

```swift
NavigationView {
    TopLevelView {
        // […]
    }
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline) // ⬅️ Important part
}
```

## SwiftUI (Xcode 11.3)

SwiftUI `navigationBarTitle` modifier has an optional `displayMode` property which you can set to `.inline` for small titles and `.large` for large titles. [See documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationbaritem/titledisplaymode)

```swift
NavigationView {
    TopLevelView {
        // […]
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("Test", displayMode: .inline) // ⬅️ Important part
}
```

---

## How it's done in UIKit

Since iOS 11, `UINavigationBar` can display its title in standard and large title mode.

On **UIKit**, if you want to choose between the two behaviors you have to set the `largeTitleDisplayMode` property of your ViewController's `navigationItem` to decide if this particular view controller should display a large title or not.

Then, you need to check the `prefersLargeTitle` property of your Navigation Controller's `navigationBar`. Setting it to `true` will allow the ViewControllers in its navigation stack to display large titles. Conversely, setting it to `false` will prevent it, overriding the preference of the individual NavigationItems present in the stack.

This will display a large title in UIKit

```swift
// Set this property to true to allow NavigationItems to display large titles
let navigationController = UINavigationController()
navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

/*
 Choose between `always`, `never` and `automatic` to decide
 if this particular view controller should display a large title.
 */
let viewController = UIViewController()
viewController.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
```

Comment: `.navigationBarTitle(displayMode:)` has been deprecated and seems not to be working in Xcode 12.0 beta 6. -_- There's a new method, `navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(_ displayMode:)` but only available iOS 14 and up.

Comment: hey @Natanel, also bumped on that. What do you think we can do for iOS < 14?

Comment: @GonçaloGaspar it's possible to use something as detailed here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58427754/3058601, but in my experience it behaves quite strangely and not smoothly. I was trying the have the fist controller on the stack use a large title but the next one inline. It only changed to inline after it already showed a large title.

Comment: @GonçaloGaspar I realized all you need to do is wrap the title string in `Text` and it should work.

Answer (score 5):

## For iOS 14 and up

Use the modifier `navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(:)` on the root view in your navigation stack.

Answer (score 2):

### Xcode 14.0+

The most robust approach is to create your own method with default value `.large`. For that you need a `View` extension. Keep using the `navigationBarTitle()` modifiers and along with that use your own ones. If you don't need the default value use `.inline` instead.

```
import SwiftUI

extension View {        
    func barTitle(_ title: String,
             size: NavigationBarItem.TitleDisplayMode = .large) -> some View {
        self.navigationBarTitle(title, displayMode: size)
    }
}

struct Benchmark: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
}
```

In Xcode 14.0+, there is a new entity called `NavigationStack`. NavigationStack is a view that displays a root view and enables you to present additional views over the root view.

[image]

```
struct OilView: View {
    
    var benchmarks: [Benchmark] = [ .init(name: "WTI"),   .init(name: "Brent"),
                                    .init(name: "Urals"), .init(name: "OPEC") ]
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            
            List(benchmarks) { benchmark in

                NavigationLink(benchmark.name, value: benchmark)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Benchmark.self) { crudeOil in

                if crudeOil.name == "WTI" || crudeOil.name == "Brent" {
                    Text("Light and Sweet")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .barTitle(crudeOil.name)    // default `.large` value
                    
                } else if crudeOil.name == "Urals" || crudeOil.name == "OPEC" {
                    Text("Heavy and Sour")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .barTitle(crudeOil.name, size: .inline)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Benchmarks", displayMode: .large)
    }
}
```

[image]