# SwiftUI can't use navigationBarTitle modifier (deprecated) in iOS 13 versions, but can in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, deprecated

I lowered my minimum deployment target from iOS 14.0 to iOS 13.0. I then got this error:

[image: 'navigationBarTitle(_:displayMode:)' is only available in iOS 14.0 or newer]

> 'navigationBarTitle(_:displayMode:)' is only available in iOS 14.0 or newer

But, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationbartitle(_:displaymode:)-8buvp) says it's available from iOS 13.0-14.2, and previous SO [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60618723/14351818) posted (back when iOS 13 was the newest) also used it.

[image]

Is it because it's "Deprecated" that I can't use it? But then why can I use it in iOS 14.0?

---

#### Edit:

After trying to reproduce, it seems to work only if I don't have `title` stored in a property.

[image: comparison of storing "title" inside a property or not]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hi!")
            .navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
struct DetailView: View {
    var title: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hi!")
            .navigationBarTitle(title, displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think: `navigationBarTitle()` has been deprecated and replaced by `.navigationTitle()`

Comment: Which Xcode version do you use?

Comment: @Asperi 12.1 (12A7403).

Comment: @Sweeper **1.** Create new SwiftUI project, **2.** Lower min deployment target to 13.0, **3.** Replace `ContentView` with `struct ContentView: View { var title: String = ""; var body: some View { Text("Hello, world!").navigationBarTitle(title, displayMode: .inline) } }`

Comment: Huh, seems to work if I remove the `title` property. The error comes back when I add it. See https://imgur.com/a/rfRCGYn. I edited my post

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you look closely at what the `navigationBarTitle` call resolves to, it isn't the method you linked:

```
func navigationBarTitle(_ title: Text, displayMode: NavigationBarItem.TitleDisplayMode) -> some View
```

It is:

[image]

```
func navigationBarTitle<S>(_ title: S, displayMode: NavigationBarItem.TitleDisplayMode) -> some View where S : StringProtocol
```

It can't resolve to the first one because you are not passing a `Text` as the title, are you? You declared the argument `title` to be a `String`.

[Here's](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationbartitle(_:displaymode:)-5071t) the documentation for the second method. From the documentation we can clearly see that it is available from iOS 14.0 to 14.2.

The reason why using a string literal as the title works (such as in `ContentView`) is because you are calling [*yet another overload*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationbartitle(_:displaymode:)-gi7a) of `navigationBarTitle`:

```
func navigationBarTitle(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, displayMode: NavigationBarItem.TitleDisplayMode) -> some View
```

`LocalizedStringKey` conforms to `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`, so string literals can be passed to an argument of type `LocalizedStringKey`, but not a variable like `title`.

Answer (score 13):

Its because you are using a string for your title instead of a Text view.

I ran into this same issue as you.

Basically in iOS 14 they added the ability to just drop a string into your nav bar directly. Prior to that you had to use `.navigationBarTitle(Text(yourString), displayMode: .inline)`

Comment: Yep! Kind of a dumb mistake.