# Get the current scroll position of a SwiftUI ScrollView

Tags: swiftui

With the new `ScrollViewReader`, it seems possible to set the scroll offset programmatically.

But I was wondering if it is also possible to **get** the current scroll position?

It seems like the `ScrollViewProxy` only comes with the `scrollTo` method, allowing us to set the offset.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59342384/how-to-detect-scroll-direction-programmatically-in-swiftui-scrollview

Answer (score 85, accepted):

It was possible to read it and before. Here is a solution based on view preferences.

```
struct DemoScrollViewOffsetView: View {
    @State private var offset = CGFloat.zero
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                    Text("Item \(i)").padding()
                }
            }.background(GeometryReader {
                Color.clear.preference(key: ViewOffsetKey.self,
                    value: -$0.frame(in: .named("scroll")).origin.y)
            })
            .onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) { print("offset >> \($0)") }
        }.coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
    }
}

struct ViewOffsetKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGFloat
    static var defaultValue = CGFloat.zero
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value += nextValue()
    }
}
```

[backup](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/Answers/Get_current_scroll_position_SwiftUI.md)

Comment: Is it possible to set it?

Comment: @Asperi - if I enclose `DemoScrollViewOffsetView` within `NavigationView{}`, I get the following warning message in the debug window when running the simulator:

`Bound preference ViewOffsetKey tried to update multiple times per frame.`

What is causing the warning/error and how can it be resolved?

Comment: I'm new to SwiftUI - this solution worked for me, but can you explain a little more about the `.background` modifier on the `VStack`? Is this just for the purposes of getting the scroll position? Thanks.

Comment: @Asperi why have you declared offset var if it is not used?

Comment: @Vee I have the same problem. Has it been solved?

Comment: @Simon - no I never figured out the root cause of the warning.  It's been a while but in my case I had nested ScrollView a that caused multiple warnings and moving them around reduced/eliminated the warning.  Like I said it was a while ago so I don't have any examples to readily share with you.  Good luck and please post if you figure it out!

Comment: @IanWarburton you can set it with the ScrollViewReader view, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollviewreader

Comment: @Asperi, If we want to identify bottom end of scroll then how we can get it ?

Comment: A word of warning. If you find this in your codebase after colleagues asked for help why their ScrollView heavily lags: Use this with caution. Have a look at the idea Adrien's answer gives you: Mutating a state this often leads to heavy body re-evaluations. For complex Views inside the ScrollView Xcodes SwiftUI Profiler shows body evaluations in a scale of thousands - for a view that's contained 3 times inside the Scrollview. Took me two days to debug.

Comment: This can't be the correct answer, the performance is _terrible_.

Answer (score 25):

I found a version without using `PreferenceKey`. The idea is simple - by returning `Color` from `GeometryReader`, we can set `scrollOffset` directly inside background modifier.

```
struct DemoScrollViewOffsetView: View {
    @State private var offset = CGFloat.zero
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                    Text("Item \(i)").padding()
                }
            }.background(GeometryReader { proxy -> Color in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    offset = -proxy.frame(in: .named("scroll")).origin.y
                }
                return Color.clear
            })
        }.coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar need but with `List` instead of `ScrollView`, and wanted to know wether items in the lists are visible or not (`List` preloads views not yet visible, so `onAppear()`/`onDisappear()` are not suitable).

After a bit of "beautification" I ended up with this usage:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            List(0..<100) { i in
                Text("Item \(i)")
                    .onItemFrameChanged(listGeometry: geometry) { (frame: CGRect?) in
                        print("rect of item \(i): \(String(describing: frame)))")
                    }
            }
            .trackListFrame()
        }
    }
}
```

which is backed by this Swift package: https://github.com/Ceylo/ListItemTracking

Comment: Is it possible to read list geometry somehow?

Answer (score 5):

The most popular answer (@Asperi's) has a limitation:
The scroll offset can be used in a function
`.onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) { print("offset >> \($0)") }`
which is convenient for triggering an event based on that offset.
But what if the content of the `ScrollView` depends on this offset (for example if it has to display it). So we need this function to update a `@State`.
The problem then is that each time this offset changes, the `@State` is updated and the body is re-evaluated. This causes a slow display.

We could instead wrap the content of the `ScrollView` directly in the `GeometryReader` so that this content can depend on its position directly (without using a `State` or even a `PreferenceKey`).

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
   content(geometry.frame(in: .named(spaceName)).origin)
}
```

where `content` is `(CGPoint) -> some View`

We could take advantage of this to observe when the offset stops being updated, and reproduce the `didEndDragging` behavior of UIScrollView

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
   content(geometry.frame(in: .named(spaceName)).origin)
      .onChange(of: geometry.frame(in: .named(spaceName)).origin, 
                perform: offsetObserver.send)
      .onReceive(offsetObserver.debounce(for: 0.2, 
                 scheduler: DispatchQueue.main), 
                 perform: didEndScrolling)
}
```

where `offsetObserver = PassthroughSubject<CGPoint, Never>()`

In the end, this gives :

```
struct _ScrollViewWithOffset<Content: View>: View {
    
    private let axis: Axis.Set
    private let content: (CGPoint) -> Content
    private let didEndScrolling: (CGPoint) -> Void
    private let offsetObserver = PassthroughSubject<CGPoint, Never>()
    private let spaceName = "scrollView"
    
    init(axis: Axis.Set = .vertical,
         content: @escaping (CGPoint) -> Content,
         didEndScrolling: @escaping (CGPoint) -> Void = { _ in }) {
        self.axis = axis
        self.content = content
        self.didEndScrolling = didEndScrolling
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(axis) {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                content(geometry.frame(in: .named(spaceName)).origin)
                    .onChange(of: geometry.frame(in: .named(spaceName)).origin, perform: offsetObserver.send)
                    .onReceive(offsetObserver.debounce(for: 0.2, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main), perform: didEndScrolling)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
        }
        .coordinateSpace(name: spaceName)
    }
}
```

Note: the only problem I see is that the GeometryReader takes all the available width and height. This is not always desirable (especially for a horizontal `ScrollView`). One must then determine the size of the content to reflect it on the `ScrollView`.

```
struct ScrollViewWithOffset<Content: View>: View {
    @State private var height: CGFloat?
    @State private var width: CGFloat?
    let axis: Axis.Set
    let content: (CGPoint) -> Content
    let didEndScrolling: (CGPoint) -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        _ScrollViewWithOffset(axis: axis) { offset in
            content(offset)
                .fixedSize()
                .overlay(GeometryReader { geo in
                    Color.clear
                        .onAppear {
                            height = geo.size.height
                            width = geo.size.width
                        }
                })
        } didEndScrolling: {
            didEndScrolling($0)
        }
        .frame(width: axis == .vertical ? width : nil,
               height: axis == .horizontal ? height : nil)
    }
}
```

This will work in most cases (unless the content size changes, which I don't think is desirable).  And finally you can use it like that :

```
struct ScrollViewWithOffsetForPreviews: View {
    @State private var cpt = 0
    let axis: Axis.Set
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollViewWithOffset(axis: axis) { offset in
                VStack {
                    Color.pink
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    Text(offset.x.description)
                    Text(offset.y.description)
                    Text(cpt.description)
                }
            } didEndScrolling: { _ in
                cpt += 1
            }
            .background(Color.mint)
            .navigationTitle(axis == .vertical ? "Vertical" : "Horizontal")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't scroll

Comment: I've just tested this code with Xcode (15.0.1) since it had been developed with an earlier version: and it works. Can you give more context @malsag ?

Comment: idk, I literally run your code with Xcode 15.0 and it doesn't scroll when I try to scroll, I even added content in VStack

Comment: I was able to make this work by wrapping the ScrollView with GeometryReader instead of other way around shown in the code. Another issue is, the initial scroll offset is not set, so it always starts from 0. How can I fix this

Answer (score 3):

Looking previous examples u can reach same result without using of PreferenceKeys.

I've updated code here to make it more flexible.

**Updated example on 2023.10.26**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct PositionReadableScrollView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    let axes: Axis.Set = .vertical
    let content: () -> Content
    let onScroll: (CGFloat) -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(axes) {
            content()
                .background(
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        let position = (
                            axes == .vertical ?
                            proxy.frame(in: .named("scrollID")).origin.y :
                            proxy.frame(in: .named("scrollID")).origin.x
                        )
                        
                        Color.clear
                            .onChange(of: position) { position, _ in
                                onScroll(position)
                            }
                    }
                )
        }
        .coordinateSpace(.named("scrollID"))
    }
}
```

How to use it

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var scrollID: CoordinateSpace = .local
    
    var body: some View {
        PositionReadableScrollView {
            ForEach(0..<100) { item in
                Text("\(item)")
            }
        } onScroll: { position in
            /// Do your checks here.
            debugPrint(position)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_PreviewProviders: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: .scrollPosition(id: $mainID) used in 2023 IOS 17

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late to the party, but I had this problem today, so I thought I'd answer. This gist includes code that will do what you need.

https://gist.github.com/rsalesas/313e6aefc098f2b3357ae485da507fc4

```
        ScrollView {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                content()
            }
            .onScrolled { point in
                print("Point: \(point)")
            }
        }
        .trackScrolling()
```

It provides extensions to get called when a ScrollView is scrolled. First use .trackScrolling on the ScrollView, then put a ScrollViewReader inside. On the ScrollViewReader use the .onScrolled extension to receive the events (one argument, a UnitPoint).

You do need to turn on scrolling tracking, I couldn't find another way to do it. Why this isn't supported...

Comment: your example code is useless without going to github page. Please expand your answer with full code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get this working without `GeometryReader` as that has terrible performance. This workaround does not give the scroll position, but solves the use case where you want to scroll to the top if not at the top.

I use this to trigger a scroll to the top of not at the top and navigate back if at the top.

```swift
struct ControllableScrollView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    @Binding var shouldReset: Bool
    @Binding var hasScrolled: Bool?

    let content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { scrollProxy in
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Color.clear
                        .id(false)
                    content()
                        .id(true)
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .onChange(of: shouldReset) {
                withAnimation { scrollProxy.scrollTo(false, anchor: .top) }
            }
            .scrollPosition(id: $hasScrolled)
        }
    }
}
```