# How to watch the ScrollView's scroll offset in another view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, vstack

I want to implement a visual effect as below the gif shows:

[image]

And I try to use a ZStack which wraps a title bar view and a ScrollView, and the opacity of the title bar changes with the scroll offset changes, is there a way to get the current offet of the ScrollView?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62588015/swiftui-get-current-scroll-position-from-scrollview

Comment: @Mofawaw ok, thanks