# How to know which rectangle is user viewing?

Tags: swiftui, uiscrollview

The following scroll view works well. It has buttons to go to next and previous Rectangles. However, the user can scroll without the buttons as well (expected functionality). Then the `currentIndex` wont change, how to make the `currentIndex` change according to the rectangle that the user is viewing?

```
         var body: some View {
                var currentIndex: Int = 0
         
        
                ScrollView {
                     
                    ScrollViewReader { value in
                                 Button("Go to next") {
                                     withAnimation {
                                     value.scrollTo((currentIndex), anchor: .top)
                                        currentIndex += 1
                                         print (currentIndex)
                                     }
                                 }
                                 .padding()
                        
                        Button("Go to previous") {
                            withAnimation {
                            value.scrollTo((currentIndex), anchor: .top)
                               currentIndex -= 1
                                print (currentIndex)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding()
        
                                 ForEach(0..<100) { i in
    ZStack {
                                     Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.red)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    Text (i)
                                     .id(i)
.onAppear{  currentIndex = i 
print (currentIndex) }

    }
                                 }
                             }
        }}
```

Edits:

If I add `.onAppear{  currentIndex = i,  print (currentIndex)` but neither it changes to the current object id and it does not get printed as well. What's the reason?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871577/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi I added `.onAppear{  currentIndex = i,  print (currentIndex)` but neither it changes to the current object id and it does not get printed as well. What's the reason?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69500827/7129318) your question? Look to the code after the edit.