# Is there any way to find out the position on screen of a SwiftUI ScrollView item?

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

I have a SwiftUI `ScrollView` that contains a `LazyVStack` of tappable elements.  When I tap on an element I wish to display a small popover at a position relative to that of the tapped element, regardless of the `ScrollView` offset.  The popover position should be consistent between targets and not simply based on the screen location.

The actual design involves blurring the entire screen on the tap and presenting a new layer with a copy of the tapped element and the popover on a new, unblurred, layer. This means that an overlay-based approach won't work in this case.

I have a solution but it feels heavyweight and wonder if I've missed a native version.

My `ScrollView` is wrapped into an OffsetReporting version (adapted from the version presented [here](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/09/24/mastering-scrollview-in-swiftui/)), so I know its current offset whenever the user scrolls.  My elements have a `GeometryReader` overlay that gets their position.  When elements are created I can combine the `ScrollView` offset and the element position and store the two as the absolute position of the element within the `ScrollView`.  When I later need to know the position on screen I can take the *current* `ScrollView` offset and adjust the stored element position accordingly.

The broad strokes are presented below.  Is there a simpler or more native way of achieving the same?

```swift
// struct and other wrapping code elided 
OffsetReportingScrollView(
    .vertical,
    showsIndicators: false,
    offsetChanged: { offset in
        // Store the ScrollView's offset.
    })
{
    ZStack {
        LazyVStack {
            ForEach(0...100, id: \.self) { (i: Int) in
                HStack {
                    Button {
                        // Enable the popover at the correct position via a property.
                    } label: {
                        Text("Item \(i)")
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.plain)
                }

                // Capture the element's position on creation                
                .overlay {
                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(Color.clear)
                            .onAppear {
                                // Store the element's position w.r.t. the ScrollView's current offset.
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62588295/12299030?

Comment: Thanks but I don't believe so, no.  I already have the ScrollView offset but want the position of individual items when I tap on them.

Comment: are you aware of the new `.onTapGesture { location in` for iOS16?

Comment: I am now, thanks!  But that only gives me the tap location, not the geometry of the tap target.  I'd like to have the popup appear at a consistent position relative to each list element.  I'll clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to just add an overlay to the selected(tapped) element. Here is a sketch:

[image]

```
struct Item: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}

struct Model {
    var items: [Item]
    init() {
        items = []
        for i in 0..<100 {
            items.append(Item(name: "Item \(i)"))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    let data = Model()
    
    @State private var selectedItem: Item? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(data.items) { item in
                Button(item.name) {
                    selectedItem = item
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .overlay(
                    Text("Info for \(item.name)")
                        .padding()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .background(.gray)
                        .opacity(selectedItem == item ? 0.9 : 0)
                        .zIndex(1)
                )
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, and it's a nice solution in the general case.  For simplicity I skipped some of the detail in my question that may have led to assumptions.  For instance I actually blur the entire screen and present an unblurred version of the tapped element - with an associated popover - on top.  For this I need the tapped element's on-screen geometry to use as an offset for the popover.  I'll make my question clearer. FWIW, the approach I suggested in the question is actually working out quite well.