# Set Image and Title in Navigation Bar in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, navigation, swiftui, uinavigationbar, swiftui-environment

[image: AppStore app has an icon with an image on the right side of the NabBar with Large Title:]
Would really appreciate it if anyone knows how to implement it or ideas on how to do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505528/swiftui-update-navigation-bar-title-color may be from the answer you can get some idea

Comment: @ Prashant Tukadiya  I have looked into this. But that is different. Thanks for sharing

Comment: As of today SwiftUI is not mature enough for this functionality. You could only do it using UIKit or hiding the navigation bar on your view and then creating a custom look-alike view that stays on the top of your screen. Afterwards it is a hard play with the gestures.

Comment: I have already created it in UIkit. But not able to create it using swiftUI.

Comment: @pushpank Did you find the answer? I am looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

> use this approach

```
    NavigationView{
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            ScrollView(.vertical){
                
                    ForEach(list, id: \.self) { item in
                            Text(item).font(.title).padding()
                    }
                }
            
            Spacer()
        }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                            Text("write something for title")
                                .font(.heavy)
                    }
                    
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                            Image("image").resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 50, alignment: .trailing)
                        }
                    }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I can only answer for the first part, which is - **How to set an image with in the title** :

(in the navigationbar)

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
            
    let array = ["thing 1", "thing 2", "thing 3", "others"]
    NavigationView{
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            ScrollView(.vertical){
                
                    ForEach(array, id: \.self) { item in
                            Text(item).font(.title).padding()
                    }
                }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                            Text("Title")
                                .font(.title)
                    }
                    
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                            Image(Constants.logoImage).resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 50, alignment: .trailing)
                        }
                    }
    }
}
}
```

hope it helps!

maybe I'll add here the animation as well in the future if I'll get into it.