# SwiftUI background color of the screen with NavigationView

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to set background color of a screen with NavigationView to be of the same color (light gray). My aim is to have the background color of every screen and navigation view background to be the same (gray) globally. How would I archive it?
I've tried this:

```
 var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.gray.opacity(0.1)
                VStack{
                    
                 Spacer()
                }
            }.navigationTitle("Today")
           
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Text("some texts"))
        }
        
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI update navigation bar title color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505528/swiftui-update-navigation-bar-title-color)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated:**
with putting Color as ignoresSafeArea!

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            ZStack {
                
                Color
                    .red
                    .ignoresSafeArea()     // <<: Here
                
                Color
                    .yellow
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .padding()
                
                
            }.navigationTitle("Today")
            
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Text("some texts"))
        }
        
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So it wasn't even UIView()
All I need was to set `.ignoresSafeArea()`

```
 Color.red.ignoresSafeArea()
```

Comment: thanks, I update the answer, at past we should use **UIView** as well but I think apple just done some update that we do not need it any more.