# How to change navigation bar tint color for pushed view in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

[**1 SOLUTION FOUND!**]
Thanks to George's comment I was able to find a solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/70353393/882987 but if somebody has any other solution feel free to write it :)

I am having some issues with setting custom navigation bar tint color in **SwiftUI** for "pushed" views.

Code is something like this, having a stack of items and tapping on each of them we show/push some detail view:

```
NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailItemView(item))) {
                        ListItemView(item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And I would like to have different navigation bar tint color for each view that gets pushed.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69227009/9607863) should help

Comment: @George are you sure? The destination View does not have NavigationView in its body, it is pushed. Is there some way to check in SwiftUI View if it is in navigation?

Comment: Oh yeah, missed that. You can still use the solution - maybe you could pass down a `Binding` of the color you want it to be to the destination? Then in the `init` of the destination view, you set that binding? You can keep passing the binding down as far as needed. Although I wonder if an environment object may work better and look cleaner.

Comment: @George I will try with Binding now, tnx

Comment: Awesome, tnx @George I used basic Binding and it works, I will post the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to George's comments I was able to find a solution, using basic **Binding**.

In the **view A** I added:

```
@State private var navColor = Color.primary
```

and I added the **modifier**:

```
NavigationView {
...
}
.accentColor(navColor)
```

And in **view B** I added:

```
@Binding var navColor: Color
```

So I can change the **navColor** property to anything I want in view B and it will update the **accentColor** (and with that the navigation bar tint color)