# How to add a title to a UIViewController that is pushed via a SwiftUI NavigationLink?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am pushing a `UIViewController` that conforms to `UIViewControllerRepresentable` on to the navigation stack from a SwiftUI View via `NavigationLink` and I would like to set the title for the ViewController.

However, I am unable to and just get an empty title. I suspect this is a SwiftUI bug but was hoping that I am perhaps missing something.

Below are the lines I have tried that don't work.

```swift
title = "Title"
navigationItem.title = "Title"
```

Here is code to reproduce the issue

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink {
                    ViewControllerRepresentable()
                } label: {
                    Text("Go to ViewController")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle(Text("SwiftUI View"))
        }
    }
}

struct ViewControllerRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = ViewController
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ViewController {
        ViewController()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "title"
        title = "title"
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI update navigation bar title color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505528/swiftui-update-navigation-bar-title-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the title in SwiftUI:

```swift
NavigationLink {
    ViewControllerRepresentable()
        .navigationTitle("My UIViewController")
} label: {
    Text("Go to ViewController")
}
```

And then your can remove these lines from your view controller unless you intend to use it in UIKit as well (in which case just `navigationItem.title` should be enough):

```swift
navigationItem.title = "title"
title = "title"
```

Comment: Argh so simple! Thank you Vadim, this works like a charm.