# How to make `VStack` view inside `ScrollView` expand up and take the space under navigation title while keeping the content in the same spot?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mobile

Here is an example of what i currenly have:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack() {
                    Text("Foo")
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, idealHeight: 200)
                .background(Color(uiColor: .systemBackground))
            }
            .background(Color(uiColor: .secondarySystemBackground))
            
            .navigationTitle("Title")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what it renders:
[image]

What i want to achieve is the white background all the way up to the top of the screen while preserving the padding so that the actual content of the `VStack` is displayed below the title and not underneath it and when scroll happens `VStack`'s content follows the title when it goes from large to inline.

Comment: So navigation bar should also be white?

Comment: Navigation bar should have white background, yes!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505528/swiftui-update-navigation-bar-title-color

Answer (score 0):

Alright, i found a way to do that. It's hacky and most probably won't work properly for all screen sizes or when changing orientation of the device but i recon it would work for most iPhone models in portrait mode.

The idea is to place a `ZStack` inside `ScrollView` and put my `VStack` there along with a `Rectangle` of required color and then offset the `Rectangle` up to occupy the space underneath the navigation bar and more to keep the color the same when scroll spring effect happens.

Here it the code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color(uiColor: .systemBackground))
                        .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.5)
                        .offset(y: -UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.5)
                        .padding(.bottom, -UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.5)
                        
                    
                    VStack() {
                        Text("Foo")
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(height: 200)
                    .background(Color(uiColor: .systemBackground))
                    
                }
            }
            .background(Color(uiColor: .secondarySystemBackground))
            
            .navigationTitle("Title")
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: don't forget to set `alignment: .top` to `ZStack`!