# How do I change the colour of a navigationTitle?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am currently experiencing the problem that the readability of my `navigationTitle("Gratitude Journal")` is bad. Can someone help me figure out how to change it?

`.foregroundColor` does not work.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI update navigation bar title color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505528/swiftui-update-navigation-bar-title-color)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the initializer of the `View`, you can provide the color using UIKit commands.

Here's how it works:

```
struct MyView: View {

    init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor(Color.blue)]   // Change blue with your desired color
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor(Color.blue)]   // Change blue with your desired color
    }

    var body: some View {
        // Whatever
    }
}
```