# How to change navigation title color in swiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

How to change navigation title color in swiftUI
Hi, There

I am learning SwiftUI, I want change navigation Title Color. I have set navigation Title using .navigationTitle("Parent Login")

I have tried to color of navigation title using below code.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            Text("Hello, World!")

                .navigationBarTitle("My Title", displayMode: .inline)

                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Text("Trailing"))

                .navigationBarTitleColor(.red) // Set the navigation title color here

        }

    }

}



extension View {

    func navigationBarTitleColor(_ color: Color) -> some View {

        return self.modifier(NavigationBarTitleColorModifier(color: color))

    }

}



struct NavigationBarTitleColorModifier: ViewModifier {

    var color: Color

    

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {

        content

            .onAppear() {

                let coloredAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()

                coloredAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor(color)]

                coloredAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor(color)]

                UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = coloredAppearance

                UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = coloredAppearance

            }

    }

}
```

I have checked apple's document but did not get proper demo or answer to change color.

Please comment if anyone has idea about it

Apple also deprecated .navigationBarTitle(<#T##title: Text##Text#>) method which takes Text styled view so we can change navigation title color. This problem happens in latest version of SwiftUI

I am trying to change navigation title color.

Comment: There's a similar question which was answered using UIViewControllerRepresentable, hope that helps! Here's the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56505528/12282360

Comment: I have tried this one also but apple deprecated it. and its not working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NavigationView` was deprecated, you should use `NavigationStack` instead. And to change navigation bar background color, try this:

```swift
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            List {
                Text("Hello, World!")
                    .frame(height: 500)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Text("Trailing"))
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                Text("My title")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
            }
        }
        .toolbarBackground(.red, for: .navigationBar)
        .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
    }
}
```

**Updated**: My mistake, I thought it was the navigation background.

<strike>Notes: `.toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)` will make navigation background color always visible. Remove this line to make it only visible if the scroll contents are under the navigation bar.</strike>

[image]

Comment: this does not address the question, "How to change navigation **title color** in swiftUI?", not the background color. The title is still black in your example.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Oh mistake in reading.... I will edit this, maybe I need a cup of coffee now.

Comment: I know the feeling very well.

Comment: Yes, Have some coffee bro :)

Comment: Haha absolutely, I edited it. However, it just works with `.inline` mode. Otherwise, you should use `UINavigationBar.appearance()` as the other answer.

Comment: This answer worked for me, I had not use ToolbarItem with .principal placement. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried it out. You can look at my example here:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]

    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundStyle(.tint)
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            .navigationTitle("Hello world")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried this one also but it is not working also

Comment: Please try this with latest SwiftUi, I am using latest SwiftUI. I have tried it but it did not work

Comment: I do iOS 17.2 and xcode version 15.1

Comment: Worked but when I use Navigationview it not worked

Comment: But NavigationView is also deprecated ;)

Comment: Yes, You are Right

Comment: So i don't know which solution you like the most, thats up to you ✅